# How to make Incremental Increases with CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I know how to increase the size of things over time using media queries but how would I do a set incremental increase. Eg. Increasing an images size `1px` per `2px`  increase in the width.

Comment: That sounds like a percentage width minus some space to me. You might look into `cal()` for this, e.g. `calc(100% - 10px)`;

Comment: How does "over time" relate to media queries?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.